# Google Analytics Linker Decorate Syntax

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We're attempting to use linker.decorate from GA on the src of an iframe.  Something along the lines of:

```
 <iframe id="whatever" class="whateveriframe" src="https://www.whatever.com/#/whatever" frameborder="0" hideadminborder="false" scrolling="no" style="width: 1px; min-width: 100%"></iframe>
```

The function we're attempting to use to alter the SRC is:

```
 function() {

   return function() {

     try { 

       var gobj = window[window.GoogleAnalyticsObject];
       var iframe = document.querySelector('.whateveriframe');
       var tracker, linker;
       if (gobj) {
          tracker = gobj.getAll()[0];
          linker = new window.gaplugins.Linker(tracker);
          iframe.src = linker.decorate(iframe.src);
       }

     } catch(e) {}

   }

 }
```

When the output returned mixes up the placement of the string being appended.  So it'll output:

```
 https://www.whatever.com/?q=valuesadded#/whatever
```

instead of what we're wanting - which is

```
 https://www.whatever.com/#/whatever?q=valuesadded
```

Shouldn't it just append the GET variables to the end of the src string?  When I output iframe.src - it's the full URL - not just the domain.

What am I missing in making it just append it to the end?

Answer (score 0):

If the query parameter is added after the hash mark it will be ignored (i.e. the value would become part of the fragment identifier instead of being an query parameter).  That's why the linker is added before the "#".

The reason for this is, basically, historical - the hash mark in links started out as signifying in-page links, and where not expected to change the page content (1). Only later they became "legit" parts of the Url (in SPAs mostly), and GA hasn't quite caught up with the fact. Attach query parameters to the end of the URl it would lead to them being ignored.

However the [linker methods have a "useAnchor" boolean parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/linker#decorate) that allow the use of the fragment identifier instead of having the linker added as query parameter. That should (haven't tested) allow you to add the linker to the "#" portion of the URl.

(1) [As one RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5) so succinctly puts it

> Fragment identifiers have a special role in information retrieval
> systems as the primary form of client-side indirect referencing,
> allowing an author to specifically identify aspects of an existing
> resource that are only indirectly provided by the resource owner.  As
> such, the fragment identifier is not used in the scheme-specific
> processing of a URI; instead, the fragment identifier is separated
> from the rest of the URI prior to a dereference, and thus the
> identifying information within the fragment itself is dereferenced
> solely by the user agent, regardless of the URI scheme.